# Limit within collect, collect's contents

Tags: arangodb, aql

So say:
`COLLECT diff = q.field INTO fielded`

Is there a way to limit length of `fielded`? I realize there's `SLICE()` function, but perhaps there is a performance optimizing `LIMIT`?

As far as I know limiting after collect will limit diff (groups) and not group contents.

Comment: In what way do you want to limit the groups? Up to 4 elements per group? Any odd elements, or particular ones? Or in other words, which ones should be discarded or don't you care?

Answer (score 0):

```
    COLLECT diff = q.field INTO fielded
    LET rest = (FOR qx IN fielded[*] LIMIT 4 return qx)
```

I don't know if this will result in performance optimizations.